# Incorrect displaying of icons in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Something weird happened with icons in my model.

They are displaying incorrectly as you can see here

[image: Here].

In other models all is just fine.

Comment: This looks like a glitch which I would expect to iron out by either restarting ArcMap/ArcCatalog (not sure where you are running ModelBuilder from) or even rebooting - if not, have you tried a copy/paste of the model to see if causing it to be re-written sorts out some corruption.

Comment: Copy/paste wont work see pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rBC81.jpg Also when trying to select the tool it wont do that, its not just a displaying bug. Selecting works fine if only clicking directly on the tool's line.

Comment: Why not?  You just close your model, right-click on it to copy, and then paste it onto the same or another toolbox.  It is then the copy that I would expect has a better chance of opening cleanly.  If not, have you tried the other two bits of advice?

Comment: I mean copy\paste not fix the problem.

Comment: What a nasty bug - have found how to solve it (cant answer own Q - low reputation):

You need to make a NEW MODEL and copy all old tools to new one. 

(Copying a whole model and pasting it wont work (restarting wont work too). Looks like this bug crushes the whole model and when  you copy-paste a model the bug is saved in a new copy.

Comment: Copying all elements inside an existing model to a new one should not be that hard using a Ctrl-A or Select All from context menu followed by a Paste  from the context menu (Ctrl-V seems not to work).

Comment: i have the very same problem here..
But it is not reproducable as it seems to occurs randomly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion (in comments) it looks like the solution is to:

1. Create a New Model
2. Edit the corrupt model and right-click within it to choose **Select All** followed by **Copy** from the context menu
3. Edit new model and right-click within it to choose **Paste** from the context menu

If you have a reproducible procedure to corrupt a model, then I would strongly recommend that you report this as a bug to Esri or your local distributor.

Comment: No, i dont know how to reproduce it.